# ipywidgets (Jupyter) trouble inside conditional

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, jupyter-notebook, conditional-statements, ipywidgets

I am looking to present a dropdown to my user and store their answer but only if a certain previous condition is met. Here is an idea of what I have so far:

```
number = 1
if (number == 1):
    name = widgets.Dropdown (
            options = [("days", 1), ("months", 2), ("years", 3)],
            value = 1,  
            description = 'choose:',
        ) 
    name
```

This dropdown appears on the screen if it is written with no conditional. But once I put it inside of the if-statement, my code runs without showing it and does not throw an error. This is my first time using ipywidgets, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [`display(name)`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Basics.html#display()) instead of just `name`, as such:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

number = 1
if (number == 1):
    name = widgets.Dropdown (
            options = [("days", 1), ("months", 2), ("years", 3)],
            value = 1,  
            description = 'choose:',
        ) 
    display(name)
```